# How to Ignore Duplicated link list from Jaws screen reader

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers

In my page - On scroll on some point of time I am cloning top navigation menu and making it as sticky menu. As I am making this fully accessibile. The JAWS link list dilog box shows two links for each anchor text. *(i.e Food, Food, Drinks, Drinks, Special Offers Special offers etc.)* It's due to top menu clone behavior.

Can any one suggest me how to ignore list of links or parent `<div>` from the link list dialog Box?

For your information I could ignore these text from tabbing by giving `tab-index="-1"`, but could not prevent from Jaws Linked list dialog menu(<kbd>insert</kbd>  + <kbd>f7</kbd>).

Comment: Maybe try adding `aria-hidden="true"` to the second `<ul>`?

Comment: Why are you duplicating the menu? Can you not reuse the menu and make it toggle between sticky and not sticky with some JavaScript and CSS?